# Opencart stylesheet changes not showing properly

Tags: css, opencart

I know that a lot of questions have been posted here about the cache and open cart.
I have a server running OC v3.0.3.2, I've been changing few default colors, some changes were applied instantly but the others required clean the cache to be displayed.

Recent changes in navigation bar modified its height
[image]

here's the code in

> /catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/stylesheet.css

```
#menu {
    background-color: #01aa83;
    /*background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #23a1d1, #1f90bb);*/
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border-color: #1f90bb #1f90bb #145e7a;
    min-height: 40px;
}
#menu .nav > li > a {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
    min-height: 15px;
    background-color: transparent;
    /*border-left: 1px solid #fff;*/
}
/*#menu .nav > li:first-child > a {
    border-left: none;
}*/
```

divs used to have a left border but I commented the line trying to figure it whats going on?

Comment: Please post your HTML as well. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @disinfor html? The problem solved itself, don't know how. Can't post url site, resides in a VPN

Comment: That's good it resolved itself, but you could easily post the HTML markup for the nav bar by copying from the source code. We don't need the URL, just the markup. CSS is nice, but we don't have a reference to what the CSS is styling.